I keep getting a npm-cli error everytime I write any npm code in terminal. How do I fix this?
On Windows, I'm getting a can't find npm-cli.js error whenever I type npm -v or any npm commands. I have node 20.13.0 installed.
The error path it gives is user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
When I looked at the path location, I found ng.cmd in the Roaming\npm folder. In the node_modules folder, I found @angular.
I thought I uninstalled all Angular libraries. How do I fix this since I don't have access to npm?

I'd highly suggest https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows

Version 20.13.0 of Node.js is broken: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/52884.

For me. Using NVM and a newer version of Node fixed everything.
